# Flink can not find groovy class during checkpoint

Tags: java, groovy, classloader, apache-flink

i have a problem in flink. my real-time compute engine use groovy script to expend compute type(like:sum、average、count adn so on). we define a standard compute interface(AbstractCompute),and if i want expand a compute type in this framework i just need impl AbstractCompute.and then store groovy script in the db. then application can read script by task and load into jvm by GroovyClassLoader.
This process does not use Flink again, depending on the work is very good。The reason is that Flink uses another ClassLoader (FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders$ChildFirstClassLoader) to load the object instantiated by the groovy script at checkpoint instead of using GroovyClassLoader.

Code

```java
// Init Groovy ClassLoader
CompilerConfiguration classLoaderConfig = new CompilerConfiguration();
classLoaderConfig.setSourceEncoding("UTF-8");
CLASS_LOADER = new GroovyClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(), classLoaderConfig);

......
......
// parse script and  new instance and put into cache
Class clazz = CLASS_LOADER.parseClass(computeType.getScript());
AbstractComputable computableObject = (AbstractComputable) clazz.newInstance();

removeComputeType(computeType);
// 自定义计算方式对象存入缓存
IndicatorCache.COMPUTABLE_OBJECT_CACHE.put(computeType.getId().intValue(), computableObject);


......
......

AbstractComputable computable = IndicatorCache.COMPUTABLE_OBJECT_CACHE.get(indicator.getComputeType());
if (computable == null) {
   if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
      log.debug("without computeType:{} in cache", indicator.getComputeType());
   }
   return false;
}
indicator.setComputableObject(computable);
```

[image]
Exception stack:

```java
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: com.xxx.xxx.common.computable.CurValueCompute
Serialization trace:
computableObject (com.xxx.xxx.common.pojo.property.IndicatorProperty)
normalIndicatorList (com.xxx.xxx.common.pojo.property.ComputeTuple)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:138)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:115)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:641)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:99)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:528)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:761)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:116)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:22)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:679)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:528)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:657)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.copy(KryoSerializer.java:231)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:577)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:554)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:534)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:718)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:696)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamMap.processElement(StreamMap.java:41)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:579)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:554)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:534)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:718)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:696)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamFilter.processElement(StreamFilter.java:40)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:579)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:554)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:534)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:718)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:696)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$ManualWatermarkContext.processAndCollectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:310)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$WatermarkContext.collectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:409)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.AbstractFetcher.emitRecordWithTimestamp(AbstractFetcher.java:398)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Kafka010Fetcher.emitRecord(Kafka010Fetcher.java:89)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Kafka09Fetcher.runFetchLoop(Kafka09Fetcher.java:154)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:738)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:94)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:58)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.run(SourceStreamTask.java:99)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:300)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:704)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxx.xxx.common.computable.CurValueCompute
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.execution.librarycache.FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders$ChildFirstClassLoader.loadClass(FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders.java:129)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:136)
        ... 41 common frames omitted
```

How to use Groovy dynamic language correctly in Flink？

Comment: This page from the Flink documentation on debugging classloading issues -- https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html#inverted-class-loading-and-classloader-resolution-order -- may help.

Answer (score 0):

Flink needs to know the types it is processing. Otherwise it is not possible to serialize and deserialize the instances. Therefore, the class definitions need to be contained in the user code jar which you submit to the Flink cluster.

If you want to support dynamically loaded classes, then you should serialize these instances into a generic format (e.g. `AbstractComputeContainer`) which you completely resolve in the user code function where you have the `GroovyClassLoader`.

Comment: First of all, I don't quite understand what you mean by serializing this dynamic type instance into a container（like `AbstractComputeContainer`）. 
When flink is doing serialization of checkpoint, how does flink know to go to this container to read the contents of this instance after serialization. Does flink have such a standard interface?
In addition, if I put the object in this container, but how to deal with flink when deserializing?

Comment: The problem with the class not found occurs when reading from Kafka. What you could do is to have a `class AbstractComputeContainer { byte[] data; }` which contains the serialized data. In your user code you can then deserialize this data using the `GroovyClassLoader`. That way Flink does not need to know about the dynamically loaded classes. The same applies to the state. Instead of storing the actual type, you should store `AbstractComputeContainer` which you deserialize in your user code.

Comment: Hello, Till Rohrmann
First of all, I am happy to receive your reply. Through your second reply.
I probably understand what you want to express, but I regret that I may not describe my problem clearly, so the scene you said is not suitable for my scene.

Comment: First, `AbstractComputable` is a service bean, not a data bean. it represents a way of calculating. 
In our system, we extend the subtype of `AbstractComputable` by adding a computational record to the database.
 Because in each calculation method record, we implement the AbstactComputable interface through the groovy script.

Comment: then application read record by task and load groovy script into jvm by `GroovyClassLoader` and  create a unique instance of the type that create by groovy script then put it into local cache .
then we can get it from cache  and calls its service method . there is no problem in these process.
but we get a exception during the checkpointing  ,it can not be serialise becase flink serialise it by `org.apache.flink.runtime.execution.librarycache.FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders.ChildFirstClassLoader` but it loaded by `GroovyClassLoader`

Comment: In fact, I have solved it by not putting it in the checkpoint process, but I think this is a very interesting and worthwhile problem, so please ask about you.

Comment: I am very sorry that it can only be sent separately due to the word limit.